# Get all checkouts on a remote workstation

Tags: c#, api, tfs

I need to get a list of all checked out files on a remote PC that is using a public workspace. I use QueryPendigSets() but the owner obtained is always the workspace owner, not the user that has checked out the file. How can i get this information? Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your team members login the remote PC and use the public workspace, the user of the pending change will be always the owner. Permissions option reserves check-in permission for the Owner.

You can login the remote PC to check whether the users for the check-out are the same.